# Cannot get response from server - communication between Android app and WAMP

Tags: php, android, wamp

I am trying to establish communication between Android app and WAMP server. To achieve that, I am using Volley and Singleton mechanism on Android side and WAMP 3.1.4 64 bit on server side.

I imagine the whole process to look like this: when I push a button, some string will be sent to WAMP server. Server will process received string and after that, it will provide response to Android app. Based on fetched response, Android app will do some further steps. I have inserted debug prints and logs on both sides and according to them, data is successfully received from Android app, but response from server seems to be missing (because Text Toast that I have put inside onResponse function isn't showed), so ether server doesn't provide response, or ether Android app doesn't process it on good way.

Only thing that came to my mind is that Firewall or Antivirus are somehow blocking communication, so I turned them off, but results were the same - Text Toast inside onResponse function wasn't called. Here is fragment of php script that runs on server side and in which I am performing processing of received data and formatting of response:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connected successfully";      
    if (isset($_POST["LocationOfDriver"])) {
        $LocationOfDriver = $_POST["LocationOfDriver"];
        $Parsed = explode("|", $LocationOfDriver);
        if (!(is_null($Parsed))) {
            $Lat = $Parsed[0];
            $Lon = $Parsed[1];
            $file = fopen($path, 'r+');
            $count = fgets($file, 1024);
            $count = $count + 1;
            fclose($file);
            $file  = fopen( $path, 'w');
            fwrite($file, $count . " " . $Lat . " " . $Lon);
            fclose($file);
            //echo json_encode(array('response' => $Lat));
            $response["response"] = "Success!";
        } else {
            echo "Nothing received";
            $response["response"] = "Failure!";
        }           
    } else {
        $LocationOfDriver = null;
        $response["response"] = "Failure!";
    }
} else {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      $response["response"] = "Failure!";
}

echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

And here is Android side fragment where I am formatting what will be sent and where I am fetching response (this method is called when I press button):

```
private void sendLocation(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                WantToParkBtn.setText("positive feedback received");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "negative feedback received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            WantToParkBtn.setText("negative feedback received");
        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map <String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{

            Map <String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("LocationOfDriver", "14.7|16.8");

            return params;
        }

    };

    MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    WantToParkBtn.setText("info sent");
}
```

To summarize, results which I get are:
1) After the press of button, Toast "Request sent" is printed and text of button is changed to "Info sent" (good behavior, that is expected)
2) on server side, when I open text file with log data, number of accesses is increased by 1 (good behavior, that is expected)
3) Nether of toasts "Success!" or "Failure!" aren't printed on Android app side (bad behavior, that is not expected - expected behavior is printing one of those two messages or error message). Are there any ideas what did go wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the `echo "Connected successfully"` line, it is certain to interfere with your later echo of the json.

Comment: YyvesLeBorg, thank you for your answer. I removed now all echo's except the one with json, but I still got no response :/ do you have any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: turn on error reporting if it is not, also block the entire code in a `try - catch` block in case you have a catchable error, it will tell you which line fails for what reason. I personally dont use any 800-pound gorilla stuff (like Volley), so i cant provide advice.  Try to see if you can get the http request status, android side. That may give you another hint.  If you get a 5XX status, your php is failing.

Comment: YvesLeBorg, thank you for help. While I was googling how to apply your advises, I found solution, so I will submit link for everybody who has this problem. This implementation works for sure:
http://www.zoftino.com/get-&-post-data-using-http-library-volley-in-android

Comment: Actually, I discovered what was the problem. It seems that the string on server side wasn't json encoded properly and I was receiving junk. Besides useful information (which is in form {"string1":"string2"}), there were a lot of unusable data, so parsing was needed. When I extracted useful data from received, everything started to work.